# Why is the change of an array argument in a method is reflected in the calling method if Java is pass-by-value?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

Why can a calling function see the modified value of an array after it's passed to a called method?  Since an array is an object, I'd assume it behaves the same as an object, but it doesn't.  Can anyone explains why?

```
public class test {
  public static void funk(int bird, int[] tiger) { 
    tiger[0] = tiger[0] * 2; 
    bird = tiger[0] + 5;
  } 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bird = 10;
    int[] tiger = {7};
    Test.funk(bird, tiger);

    //bird: 10 --> Not changed
    System.out.println("bird:"+bird);           
    //tiger: [14] --> Changed 
    System.out.println("tiger:"+Arrays.toString(tiger));
  }
}
```

Comment: `int[]` is not a primitive type.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - The OP has already mentioned that he has gone through the post used to mark this question as *duplicate*. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind That doesn't make it any less of a duplicate. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18740042/438154) answer addresses arrays.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - You are right. He should go through that post *again* :)

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't behave like an object?